# How does Solidity decode a struct returned from a delegate call?

Tags: contract-invocation, struct, delegatecall, decoding, dsproxy

I have a proxy contract that delegate calls to a target contract. The proxy is similar to [DSProxy](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-proxy/tree/master/src).

In it, there is an `execute` function:

```
function execute(address target, bytes memory data) external payable returns (bytes memory response) {
    // ...
    (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.delegatecall(data);
    // ...
}
```

Whose job is to delegate call to the provided `target` and return the `response`, which is of type `bytes memory`.

Now, say that I am calling a target contract that returns a struct:

```
contract TargetEcho {
    struct TargetStruct {
        uint256 foo;
        uint256 bar;
    }

    function echoStruct(TargetStruct calldata input) external pure returns (TargetStruct calldata) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

The Solidity compiler must do something to the `TargetStruct calldata` return type. It must decode it somehow. How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's figure this out empirically with [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js):

```
const input = { foo: BigNumber.from("3"), bar: BigNumber.from("1") };
const data: string = targetEcho.interface.encodeFunctionData("echoStruct", [input]);
const response = await proxy.callStatic.execute(target, data);
console.log({ input, response });
```

That produces the following output:

```js
{
  input: {
    foo: BigNumber { _hex: '0x03', _isBigNumber: true },
    bar: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true },
  },
  response: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
}
```

Thus the answer is that Solidity unpacks the struct fields and concatenates their values, disregarding the keys. This makes it compatible with the `bytes memory` type of the `response` variable defined in the proxy contract.

Luckily ethers.js is able to decode the response string:

```js
const decodedResponse = targetEcho.interface.decodeFunctionResult("echoStruct", response);
```

Output:

```js
{
  decodedResponse: [
    [
      [BigNumber],
      [BigNumber],
      foo: [BigNumber],
      bar: [BigNumber],
    ]
  ]
}
```